# Error starting Ruby Passenger on Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, passenger

I have a problem with starting a Ruby 2.0 gear on my openshift account. Everything was fine until a restart when suddenly something went wrong and I cannot start my server. This is an error message I get:

```
[03/Mar/2016:17:57:07 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "-"
[03/Mar/2016:17:57:06 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "-"
[03/Mar/2016:17:58:37 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15     (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
- - - [03/Mar/2016:17:58:38 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-"     "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:43.5501 121817/7f7c2874f700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App     155223 stdout]
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4548 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App     155223 stderr] WARN: Unresolved specs during
Gem::Specification.reset:
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4549 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:151 ]: [App     155223 stderr]
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4551 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App     155223 stderr]       rack (>= 0)
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4552 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:151 ]: [App     155223 stderr]
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4553 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App     155223 stderr] WARN: Clearing out unresolved
specs.
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4554 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:151 ]: [App     155223 stderr]
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4555 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App     155223 stderr] Please report a bug if this ca
uses problems.
[ 2016-03-03 18:06:51.4556 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:151 ]: [App     155223 stderr]
[ 2016-03-03 18:08:13.5552 121817/7f7c2874f700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849     ]: Could not spawn process for group /var/li
b/openshift/5631ccf70c1e66dcef000130/app-root/runtime/repo#default: An error     occurred while starting the web application
: it did not write a startup response in time.
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::throwAppSpawnException(const     std::string&, Passenger::SpawnException
::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)'     (Spawner.h:666)
     in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr     Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::negotiateSpawn(Passenger::Applica
tionPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1135)
 in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::DirectSpawner::spawn(const Passeng
er::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (DirectSpawner.h:213)
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, co
nst Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)
[ 2016-03-03 18:08:13.5554 121817/7f7c235fe700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1971 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout s
ession. An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
Error page:
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  rack (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
91.238.59.70 - - [03/Mar/2016:18:06:43 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 682 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWe
bKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36"
[ 2016-03-03 18:10:23.7613 121817/7f7c2874f700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 166543 stdout]
[ 2016-03-03 18:10:30.9478 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App 166543 stderr] WARN: Unresolved specs during
Gem::Specification.reset:
[ 2016-03-03 18:10:30.9478 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App 166543 stderr]       rack (>= 0)
[ 2016-03-03 18:10:30.9478 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App 166543 stderr] WARN: Clearing out unresolved
specs.
[ 2016-03-03 18:10:30.9478 121817/7f7c2870e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App 166543 stderr] Please report a bug if this ca
uses problems.
```

and here's my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

### OpenShift Online changes:

# Fix the conflict with the system 'rake':
gem 'rake', '0.9.6'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'rack', '~> 1.5.2'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.9'
# Support for databases and environment.
# Use 'sqlite3' for testing and development and mysql and postgresql
# for production.
#
# To speed up the 'git push' process you can exclude gems from bundle install:
# For example, if you use rails + mysql, you can:
#
# $ rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development test postgresql"
#
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'thor'
end


# Add support for the MySQL

group :production, :postgresql do
  gem 'pg'
end

### / OpenShift changes

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~>2.5.3'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
#gem 'spring'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
gem 'log4r'
gem 'mail'
gem 'activejob'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "daemons"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", :git => 'https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2', :branch => 'master'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'savon'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'chartkick'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.9'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

and here's gemfile.lock

```
  GIT
  remote: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2
  revision: e505783c33d51c0b0db1c8e595539b4fde30d6d6
  branch: master
  specs:
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.10)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth (>= 1.1.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.3.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activejob (0)
      activemodel-globalid
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    activemodel (4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activemodel-globalid (0.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    activerecord (4.1.4)
      activemodel (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.4)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    akami (1.3.1)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    bcrypt (3.1.10-x64-mingw32)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (8.1.0)
    chartkick (1.4.1)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_job (4.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    domain_name (0.5.25)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.10-x64-mingw32)
    gyoku (1.3.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    hashie (3.4.3)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httpi (2.4.1)
      rack
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.2)
    log4r (1.1.10)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.2)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.20)
    mysql2 (0.3.20-x64-mingw32)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    nori (2.6.0)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-facebook (3.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    pg (0.18.3)
    pg (0.18.3-x64-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      activemodel (= 4.1.4)
      activerecord (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails4-autocomplete (1.1.1)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    railties (4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.6)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    rest-client (1.8.0-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    savon (2.11.1)
      akami (~> 1.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.2)
      httpi (~> 2.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 2.4)
      wasabi (~> 3.4)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11-x64-mingw32)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.7)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1-x64-mingw32)
    validates_email_format_of (1.6.3)
      i18n
    wasabi (3.5.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.2)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    wicked_pdf (1.0.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.7)
    wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activejob
  acts_as_commentable
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.9)
  byebug
  chartkick
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  daemons
  delayed_job_active_record
  i18n (= 0.6.9)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  log4r
  mail
  minitest
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.18)
  nokogiri
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2!
  pg
  rack (~> 1.5.2)
  rails (= 4.1.4)
  rails4-autocomplete
  rake (= 0.9.6)
  rest-client
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  savon
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sqlite3
  thor
  turbolinks (~> 2.5.3)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  validates_email_format_of
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  wicked_pdf
  will_paginate
  wkhtmltopdf-binary

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Comment: Did you try using the `force_clean_build` [marker file](https://developers.openshift.com/en/ruby-markers.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a problem with the rack gem. You can try:

- `bundle clean --force`
- `gem cleanup rack`

You might have to run those commands with sudo depend on which user passenger is running under.

Comment: unfortunately that did not help + I cannot really use sudo there